# Using a string for an Android intent putExtra() method

Tags: android, android-intent

I am using an Android intent to create a calendar event. Do all intent extras have string names? For example, instead of using

```
.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "New event")
```

I can use:

```
.putExtra("title", "New event")
```

Is there something like that for all intent extras? For example, instead of using `CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME`, is there a string literal I can use? Or maybe I'm way off, and the "title" is not actually working the way I expect it to?

I have looked over [calendar intent documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider#intents) several times, as well as the documentation on [putExtra()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20android.os.Parcelable%5B%5D)) and general [intent documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent), as well as several StackOverflow posts, but I can't figure it out. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for `CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME`   its `beginTime` .

You can ctrl+click to see each string respective name in android studio .

Also it is not recommended to use hardcoded string always use `CalendarContract.Events.TITLE` instead of `title`

Comment: Thanks! It looks like their official name is "Constant Value" ([source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract#EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME)). Do you know what the format of the time has to be? I am using a value of `1596283200000` (August 1, 2020, 12:00 PM), but it doesn't seem to be working. It may just be that the application I am using to interface with the intents can't take it, although the "allDay" parameter can successfully take a value of `true`.